# Where to add the code for checking in app updates in android, would it be fine if I do it in the splash screen? or the mainActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-update

I was going through in-app updates library (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) and want to add this functionality, however I am confused about where to add the code to check if the update is available, I couldn't any information regarding this.
If I add the code to the splash screen will it increase the waiting time? Any best practice advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to add your code in activity which appear after splash screen,Cause in app update show popup and dialog and also check in playstore for any update.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code in activity which is your Base activity for application i.e always present when you app running either in pause/resume state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add app update code after splash screen. In main activity first check about your app update then perform other task.